# Pass back array as a parameter

Tags: c

So I need to be able to pass back this struct array I created inside the function as a parameter, not the return value and I am at a loss. Can someone show me the optimal way of doing this? Thank you!

```
int calcHistogram(char** arr, Histogram* h,  int count) {

  Histogram* hist = (Histogram*)malloc(count*sizeof(Histogram));
  int hCount = 0;

  // Code that works
  
  h = hist;
  return hCount;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [malloc in a function doesn't work well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541990/malloc-in-a-function-doesnt-work-well)

Comment: Like all other values, pointers are passed *by value*, meaning the value in the call is *copied* into the argument variable of the function. Modifying this copy will not modify the original value. Please do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: @kaylum thank you I remember going over this in a video lecture this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: `h = hist` assign address only to local pointer h. you could use `*h = *hist` or double pointer at parameter `h`

Comment: What's `arr` for? Seems you have managed to confuse yourself with that one, change the function to `int calcHistogram(Histogram** h,  int count)` and it should become clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need a function like this:

```c
int createHistogram(char **arr, Histogram **h, int count) {
    Histogram *hist = (Histogram *)malloc(sizeof(Histogram) * count);
    int hCount = 0;

    // Code that works

    *h = hist;
    return hCount;
}
```

Then you can declare a pointer

```c
Histogram *h;
```

and then call

```c
createHistogram(arr, &h, count);
```

to store the address of the array of histograms into `h`.

Comment: I'd get rid of the other parameters that do nothing and are unused. In this case `arr` can go and you can remove `hCount` and simply `return 0;` The answer may be lost in the superfluous information. The other alternative is to make the function type `Histogram *` and return a pointer to the allocated block. (either way is fine)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - "I'll get rid ...." - Perhaps those parameters are used in "/* code that works*/" along with hCount.

Comment: Yep, I can see it both ways. Certainly not coming from an MCVE...