# Struct pointer not updating when passed to function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a header file and two source files.

Below is the code in my `tpool_pq.h` file.

```
typedef enum priority_t {LOW = 1, MEDIUM = 3, HIGH = 5} priority_t;

typedef struct task_t {
    void (*function)();
    void *arguments;
    priority_t priority;
} task_t;

typedef struct tpool_pq {
    task_t *task_array;
    int n_tasks;
    int queue_size;
} tpool_pq_t;

int init_tpool_pq(tpool_pq_t *tpool_pq, int queue_size);
```

source file for `tpool_pq.c`

```
#include "tpool_pq.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int init_tpool_pq(tpool_pq_t *tpool_pq, int queue_size) {

    if ((tpool_pq = (tpool_pq_t *) malloc(sizeof(struct tpool_pq))) == NULL)
        printf("malloc returned null\n");
    
    tpool_pq->n_tasks = 0;
    tpool_pq->queue_size = queue_size;
    tpool_pq->task_array = (task_t *)malloc(sizeof(task_t)*queue_size);
}
```

Code in main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tpool_pq.h"

void main() {
    tpool_pq_t *pq;
    int task_queue_size = 32;
    init_tpool_pq(pq, task_queue_size);
    printf("size: %d \n", pq->queue_size);
    
}
```

The pointer `pq` is passed to `init_tpool_pq()`. The changes in `init_tpool_pq` are not reflected outside of the function. `printf` statement in `main.c` prints size as some garbage value `1230389504` instead of 32.

I couldn't find the reason for why the changes are not reflected.

Comment: everything in C is pass-by-value, including pointers. If you want changes to a pointer to persist outside of the function, you must pass a pointer to it (a pointer to a pointer), then dereference and make changes to the thing it points to, just the same as anything else. Or your function can return a pointer. Tons of dupes, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c) looks like a higher traffic one.

Comment: OT: The error message is good (when `malloc()` fails) BUT it's not good to continue on and use a NULL pointer... And, 2nd `malloc()` is not verified... And, really OT: Recommend that you use `calloc()` instead... And, don't cast the return from `m/calloc()`...

Comment: If you're at the stage where you are implementing thread pools, it's really time to step back and make sure you've covered the basics of C. The concept of reflecting changes back to the caller is covered in any reputable book, shortly after introducing you to the concept of functions.

Comment: Another much asked question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398307/how-can-i-allocate-memory-and-return-it-via-a-pointer-parameter-to-the-calling https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541990/malloc-in-a-function-doesnt-work-well

Answer (score 3):

You change `init_tpool_pq`'s `tpool_pq`. This is a different variable than `main`'s `pq`.

---

**Option 1: Return the pointer**

```c
tpool_pq_t *new_tpool_pq( size_t queue_size ) {
   tpool_pq_t *tpool_pq = malloc( sizeof( tpool_pq_t ) );
   if ( !tpool_pq  )
      goto ERROR1;

   task_t *task_array = malloc( sizeof( task_t ) * queue_size );
   if ( !task_array )
      goto ERROR2;
    
   tpool_pq->n_tasks    = 0;
   tpool_pq->queue_size = queue_size;
   tpool_pq->task_array = task_array;

   return tpool_pq;

ERROR2:
   free( tpool_pq );
ERROR1:
   return NULL;
}

int main( void ) {
   size_t task_queue_size = 32;

   tpool_pq_t *tpool_pq = new_tpool_pq( task_queue_size );
   if ( !tpool_pq ) {
      perror( "new_tpool_pq" );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
   }

   ...
}
```

---

**Option 2: Pass a pointer to the variable**

```c
int new_tpool_pq( tpool_pq_t **tpool_pq_pp, size_t queue_size ) {
   tpool_pq_t *tpool_pq = malloc( sizeof( tpool_pq_t ) );
   if ( !tpool_pq  )
      goto ERROR1;

   task_t *task_array = malloc( sizeof( task_t ) * queue_size );
   if ( !task_array )
      goto ERROR2;
    
   tpool_pq->n_tasks    = 0;
   tpool_pq->queue_size = queue_size;
   tpool_pq->task_array = task_array;

   *tpool_pq_pp = tpool_pq;
   return 1;

ERROR2:
   free( tpool_pq );
ERROR1:
   *tpool_pq_pp = NULL;
   return 0;
}

int main( void ) {
   size_t task_queue_size = 32;

   tpool_pq_t *tpool_pq;
   if ( !new_tpool_pq( &tpool_pq, task_queue_size ) ) {
      perror( "new_tpool_pq" );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
   }

   ...
}
```

---

Notes:

- Sends the error to STDERR.
- Includes the error in the error message.
- Doesn't proceed after the memory allocation failure.
- Checks the second `malloc` too.
- Uses a legal prototype for `main`.
- Let's the caller handle the error, to keep separate concerns separate.
- I use `new` for an allocating constructor, and `init` for a constructor that initializes an existing structure.